# Why WSGIDaemonProcess isn't available on Windows?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Why isn't WSGIDaemonProcess available on Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't mod\_wsgi support daemon mode on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364949/why-doesnt-mod-wsgi-support-daemon-mode-on-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

> On the Windows platform there is no
>   daemon mode only embedded mode. The
>   MPM used on Apache is the 'winnt' MPM.
>   This MPM is like the worker MPM on
>   UNIX systems except that there is only
>   one process.

Seems pretty clear.  Need more information?

Comment: Thanks. I need to read up on the differences between embedded and daemon mode. I just learned through examples how to get multiple sites going in daemon mode. Now on windows, i was at a bit of a loss. Thanks for the link.

Comment: FYI - the underlying reason Apache (and others) lack daemon features under Windows is due to Window's lack of an equivalent to the Unix `fork()` call, which Apache relies on. Not that it's impossible to replicate, it's just that the primitives Windows offers are so conceptually different that it'd massively alter how Apache's daemon features worked. To see why Apache didn't bother, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork for details about cygwin's (hairy) attempt.