# mod_wsgi daemon mode on windows using cygwin for fork?

Tags: windows, fork, mod-wsgi

So I can't use mod_wsgi in daemon mode on windows becuase it [doesn't support fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364949/why-doesnt-mod-wsgi-support-deamon-mode-on-windows) like a UNIX system. But at the same time, [I can use Cygwin for doing fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork) on windows. Can I somehow combine the two to allow daemon mode on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you can also install and get Apache and Python working under cygwin first. You would not be able to mix a cygwin compiled mod_wsgi with normal Apache and Python windows binaries. You may also have to manually fiddle with the makefiles to construct one that will build under cygwin as not sure that the configure script will necessarily run under cygwin.

Comment: Which is to say - possible, but way over my head. There's no other current solution - existing or in the works - to allow this, right? I sadly cannot move to a unix server at this time and would like to use daemon on my production server