# Does Interix implement fork()?

Tags: windows, linux, posix, fork, interix

On *Unix to Windows Porting Dictionary for HPC* [page](http://www.suacommunity.com/dictionary/fork-entry.php) for fork() it's written

> There is no equivalent Windows API to
>   the Unix fork() or vfork(). The
>   Microsoft Subsystem for Unix-based
>   Applications (SUA or Interix) is a
>   Unix environment that has fork() and
>   vfork() properly implemented.

and further on the page there's example source code which uses... standard Win32 API `CreateProcess` function.

I'm confused.
Shouldn't the example use fork() to illustrate the statement about fork() being implemented by SUA/Interix?
If fork() is really implemented which header and lib files does it live in?

Comment: Related questions: [What is the closest thing windows has to fork()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/), [substitute for fork()ing? in windows.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243880/), [CreateThread vs fork()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619019/), [fork/chroot equivalent for Windows server application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686578/), [Where does Microsoft Windows 7 POSIX implementation currently stands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746043/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you're looking at is the *nix to Windows porting guide. It doesn't show you how to use `fork()` but the closest win32 equivialent, `CreateProcess`. The pages there documents which Win32 function you should use instead of Unix functions.

You'll need the subsystem for Unix and the [SUA SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=dc03485b-629b-49a6-b5ef-18617d1a9804) to use `fork()`. There you'll get a *nix environment on Windows, `fork()` will be in the usual `unistd.h` library, and you'll link to `libc.so` (using gcc) to use it.

Comment: Are there any online docs for this SDK listing available functions the same way MSDN lists Win32 API functions? I know there are plenty docs for POSIX but I'm curious if there's online documentation for this particular SDK?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: The only documentation I've seen is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754234.aspx), which is pretty much nothing.